# Under which specific (formal) conditions can I apply the superposition theorem?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-source, superposition

Superposition theorem fails when you have two ideal (identical) voltage sources in parallel. Under which specific constraints can I apply it?

I have read that, in DC Circuits, superposition requires that ideal voltage sources are never placed in parallel, and ideal current sources are never placed in series. Is this true?

I have tried to apply it to the following circuit, with R1 = 0.25 ohms, R2 = 0.32 ohms and V1  = V2 = 1.5V, but I'm getting absurd results:

[image]

Comment: So can you show us your work?

Comment: Also, your result. One version of the circuit should be with the V1 = 0V (turned off and thus replaced by a short-circuit). The other version is with V2 turned off and should yield an identical circuit since V1 = V2, except the polarities are in the opposite direction. Therefore, the currents in each version are identical but opposing and therefore when superimposed cancel out and equal zero.

Comment: Superposition will work for this circuit...the circuit you provided as a schematic is not the same as what you described originally. Show us your work.

Answer (score 5):

The superposition theorem works for any linear circuit.

The problem with two voltage sources in **parallel** is that if their voltages are not identical then you have a **nonsense** circuit. Two different voltage sources in parallel will violate either or definition of **parallel** or our definition of an **ideal voltage source**.

EDIT after OP provides a schematic:
The circuit you provided **does not** have ideal voltage sources in parallel. Superposition will work.

Comment: To add, connecting two ideal voltage sources together is analogous to writing "3 = 5". It's nonsense within the framework of schematics like "3 = 5" is nonsense within the framework of arithmetic expressions.

Comment: This is correct, superposition applies to any linear system. Unfortunately this is a tautology, since the definition of a linear system boils down to "a system where superposition applies".